# How to style nested elements in react with styled-components?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using styled components and would like to style a child inside a div via nested css. See my demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/q8oqrwwwkj)

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    ...theme.typography.button,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit,
    ">span": {
      background: "red"
    }
  }
});

function TypographyTheme(props) {
  return (
    <div className={props.classes.root}>
      <h1>
        <span>{"This div's text looks like that of a button."}</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like JSS syntax, not styled component.

Change this:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    ...theme.typography.button,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit,
    ">span": {
      background: "red"
    }
  }
});
```

With this:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    ...theme.typography.button,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit,
    "& span": {
      background: "red"
    }
  }
});
```

or if you wouldn't that change all nested spans

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    ...theme.typography.button,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit,
    "& > h1 > span": {
      background: "red"
    }
  }
});
```

Try this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/vm3qnmj75l

For reference:
http://cssinjs.org/jss-nested/

Comment: wouldn't that change all nested spans instead of only the root children like in OP post