# What is the best way to style nested elements in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to style several div elements using CSS. In normal CSS it is possible to use the following code:

```
.wrapper{
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  .container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 20%;
    .inside {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

However in order to use the same CSS in CSS modules it requires to write it as follows:

```
.wrapper{
      width: 300px;
      height: 500px;
}

.wrapper .container {
        width: 50%;
        height: 20%;
}

.wrapper .container .inside {
          color: red;
        }
```

Is there a better and simpler way to do this? Since when having many elements this method seems to be more complicated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style nested elements in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022653/how-to-style-nested-elements-in-react)

Comment: I tried that solution before and it doesn't work in the CSS file.

Comment: Have you looked into SASS? It's great for nested CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_sass.asp

Comment: Try styled components then, it supports nested css.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the first example is *not* valid in CSS.  It is in SASS/SCSS.  The second example is valid in CSS, not just CSS Modules.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the styled-components library.

An example would be

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;

    &.container{
        width: 50%;
        height: 20%;

        &.inside{
            color:red;
        }
    }

`
```

However i would recommend to do it in a more react-way

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
`
const Container = styled.div`
    width: 50%;
    height: 20%;
`
const Inside = styled.div`
    color: red;
`
```